# Name for this pattern in woven fabric

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm looking for the term for this type of fabric - where the contrasting pattern/relief is made from weave differences in a single color, rather than embroidery or the use of different colors of thread.

I know one exists, but I can't recall what it is and it's driving me crazy.

[image: Sample, made with cotton]

Comment: ***Textured facric*** ? A textured surface is not smooth, but has a particular texture, for example, it feels rough. http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/textured_1

Comment: Yes, it's a type of textured fabric - but there's a specific word for it.  I want to say "jacquard" by analogy with the loom but I don't think that's it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is called [*damask*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damask) and, yes, it is woven on a jaquard loom. Damasks can be self-coloured (same coloured weft and warp threads), which is what you have in your picture.

Comment: @Mick - no, damask has different patterns and usually a heavier fabric as per the pictures from your link.

Answer (score 5):

Your fabric is an example of a *damask* weave, probably in linen. It is difficult to tell from the image whether it is an ordinary (single) damask or a double damask.

The Wikipedia article linked to is not very helpful since it only shows furnishing damasks, which tend to be very heavy. The V&A website has plenty of examples of table linen but the images are not detailed since they are of entire pieces. Thomas Ferguson's website gives a much better impression of modern linen damasks.

[Wikipedia: Damask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damask)

[Victoria & Albert Museum: Linen damask napkin](http://collections.vam.ac.uk/item/O360207/napkin/)

[Thomas Ferguson Irish Linen: Fine Irish linen damask](http://www.fergusonsirishlinen.com/shop/viewlistbyrange.asp?CatName=Table-Linen&rangeName=Fine-Irish-Linen-Damask&CatID=1&rangeID=1)

Comment: Great minds ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I think you're thinking of **damask**. Your intuition that it's related to jacquard is on-point, since those looms can be used to make a "damask-look" material (see [this post on *The Dreamstress*](http://thedreamstress.com/2014/07/brocade-and-jacquard-whats-the-difference-or-the-history-of-the-jacquard-loom-and-all-the-weaves-it-can-create/) for a comparison of brocade, jacquard, and damask).

A general definition:

> **Damask** (Arabic: دمسق‎‎) is a reversible figured fabric of silk, wool,
>   linen, cotton, or synthetic fibres, with a pattern formed by weaving.
>   Damasks are woven with one warp yarn and one weft yarn, usually with
>   the pattern in warp-faced satin weave and the ground in weft-faced or
>   sateen weave.
>   ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damask))

And from a textile-themed website article (emphasis mine):

> [R]eal damask is actually a type of fabric which uses a variety of
>   weaving techniques (most commonly satin and twill variants) to create
>   areas of different sheen in the cloth. Because the different textures
>   reflect light differently, **the patterns show as variations in tone**,
>   and sometimes the weave is given even further emphasis by using
>   different colours in the warp and weft. ([Julie Gibbons, "History of
>   Surface Design: Damask" PatternObserver.com](http://patternobserver.com/2015/03/31/history-surface-design-damask/))

Note that not all damasks are monochrome, and sometimes the term is used to describe patterns typical of some damask fabric (elaborate and scroll-y).

Some examples of damask table linens:

[image: Google Image Search for damask weave linens]

---

(And I just noticed that this has been answered in comments by @Mick while I was composing the answer; I'm going to post it anyway, in case folks want some additional references. I can make it a community wiki if that's the right etiquette.)

Comment: Well done. You're a lot quicker than me.

Answer (score 0):

How about ***dobby***?

From Dictionary.com:

> [**dobby**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dobby?s=t): An attachment on a loom, used in weaving small patterns. / Also called
>   **dobby weave**. A small geometric or floral pattern produced by this attachment. / A fabric having such a pattern.

Also see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobby_(cloth)):

> **Dobby** is a woven fabric produced on the dobby loom, characterised by small geometric patterns and extra texture in the cloth. *The warp
>   and weft threads may be the same colour or different.* Satin threads
>   are particularly effective in this kind of weave as their texture will
>   highlight the pattern. [emphasis added]

I happen to some white dobby dress shirts, Polo by Ralph Lauren.

Comment: It would be possible to weave damask on a dobby loom but the patterns would be very small. Orginally, damasks would have been hand-woven. These days, they are made on computerised jacquard looms.

Comment: @Mick Thanks. Good to know. The patterns [here](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=dobby+weave+images&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) do appear to be on the small side.